# Android : Xml listview showing error while using in TabgroupActivity

Tags: android

I am using Tab Activity. In one of the Tab Child i used list Activity. 
If i declared listview inside Activity by using "new" means it working fine. But when i used the listview which declared in .xml file ,it showing application force close error.

In `TabActivity`, we have to use `listview` means any rules is there ,...... Please specify

Comment: Hi , the error report is :    02-04 10:34:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Ripple/com.Ripple.FriendsListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.


 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I think you have to clear adapter if you use otherwise please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are following ActivityGroup Implemanetation for tab implementation, which needs parent activity context, while listView inflating from xml, get Context from current Activity, so this error is occuring.

Comment: hi , yes i am following Activity group implementation ... the error getting is 02-04 10:34:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Ripple/com.Ripple.FriendsListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.


 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: are you calling someLayout.addView(listVIew); method.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would suggest you to create separate Activity which populates your ListView. I mean, create an Activity which extends ListActivity and do your ListView related job inside it. Then create an intent and add this extended ListActivity as a child of your TabHost. In [this blog post](http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/6783812456/android-tab-layout) I have explained how to add a simple Activity as a child of a tabhost. Instead of extending an Activity as explained in the blog post, try extending a List activity there. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt with either the blog post or this answer.

The complete resource on how you could extend a ListActivity is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).
Here is some code for your reference :

```
public class TestlistActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final String [] str = {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};
        ArrayAdapter<Object> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        setListAdapter(adapt);
    }
}
```

Add a listview in the XML and id should be @android:id/list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```